# Specman reflection: How to get the value of simple port, when its name is given as a string?

Tags: reflection, specman

I need to get the value of a simple port, while the only information I have is the port's name (as a string).
Something like this:

```
my_meth(port_type : string) is { //e.g.: port_type = "signal_map.some_port$"
    var rf_port_val : rf_value_holder = rf_manager..??? //How to get port's value by its name using port_type?

    // do something...
};
```

How can it be done? 
In addition, I could not find any useful documentation about Specman reflection, may be you can refer me to such?
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find information about reflection in the documentation.
In your prompt, you can run "cdnshelp" to reach the docs.
From there, you can search for "Reflection Interface" or "rf_manager" to reach the documentation about the reflection facility in e.
The specific path is under Incisive Enterprise Simulator --> Specman Functional Verification --> Creating e testbenches --> 15. Reflection Interface for e.

In addition, there is a handy set of HTML files with "edoc" documentation of 
the API under -->
*(installation root*)/specman/docs/reflection_api_edoc/index.html
This contains a handy API reference for the different reflection structs.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer this directly, but can you not solve this easier by using a macro?
Such as

```
define <my_meth'exp> "my_meth\(<any>\)" as {
  <any>
};
```

Comment: Caveat: this only works if you pass a string-literal (w/o the double-quotes) to the method: var x: bit = my_meth(signal_map.some_port$);